# hsql gives exception executing this statement

Tags: sql, spring, hsqldb

I am trying to run my integration test for my Spring Cloud Task Batch Application using in memory hsql db and it gives me the below error executing this db statement. This statement executes fine in sqlserver db. Is there some syntax change I need to do? Thanks!

**Table Create Query**

```
CREATE TABLE TASK_SEQ (
    ID BIGINT NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE_KEY CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    constraint UNIQUE_KEY_UN unique (UNIQUE_KEY)
);
```

**Insert Query**

```
INSERT INTO TASK_SEQ (ID, UNIQUE_KEY) select * from (select 0 as ID, '0' as UNIQUE_KEY) as tmp;
```

**Error Stacktrace**

```
Caused by:

org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException:
  Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of class path resource
  [schema-DML.sql]: INSERT INTO TASK_SEQ (ID, UNIQUE_KEY) select * from
  (select 0 as ID, '0' as UNIQUE_KEY) as tmp; nested exception is
  java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: )     at
  org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:491)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable SQL Server compatibility in HSQLDB. See the Guide:

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/compatibility-chapt.html#coc_compatibility_mssql

Your statement looks unnecessarily complex. Something like below should work in most databases.

```
INSERT INTO TASK_SEQ (ID, UNIQUE_KEY) VALUES (0, '0')
```